# Make TCP to reconnect automatically and quickly

Tags: networking, apt, tcp, tuning

In my Debian Linux system `apt-get dist-upgrade` is sometimes stalled with `[Waiting for headers]` message.

To make it pass faster I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and start the command again.

How to tune the system to avoid stalling and disconnect and reconnect automatically when a stalled connection may be detected?

Comment: I think that you are approaching the problem using the wrong angle. You should first try changing mirrors.

Comment: I also think the approach is misguided. A nicely configured network should always attempt to let the client that TCP communication is not possible. Thus it is a good idea to update (1) from known good networks (2) using known good mirrors. Also bad mirrors shouldn't be in the official list. If a TCP connection gets stalled, that's typically a symptom of a more serious issue somewhere. If you want to know more about what's happening, `strace -e socket` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but you can change Linux's TCP connection time out values, temporarily, by writing the new number of retries to the networking stack's proc interface.

as root: `echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2`

From the Linux TCP man page:

> The default value is 15, which corresponds to a duration of approximately between 13 to 30 minutes.

Be careful when changing these values, because being able to retransmit when an ACK is not received for an existing connection is a large part of the difference between TCP and UDP, and there's a reason everybody likes using TCP.

`tcp_retries1` also exists, but it's for slightly different purposes and is already by default at the lowest value recommended by RFC.